# Can't copy the blanklines of my RichTextBox

Tags: .net, vb.net, richtextbox, notepad, richtext

I'm trying to copy the entire text of a RichTextBox to the clipboard.

This is how I append the text in the RichTextbox:

```
RichTextBox1.Text += vbNewLine & AlbumName
RichTextBox1.Text += vbNewLine & AlbumLink & vbNewLine
RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = RichTextBox1.Text.Length
RichTextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
```

But I can't recognize the vbnewline (tried also using VBCrlf):

```
Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripMenuItem2.Click
    Clipboard.SetText(RichTextBox1.Text.Replace(vbNewLine, "              "))
End Sub
```

The notepad can't recognize that blank lines when I paste the text, but if I paste the same copied text into other TextEditor for example in "**SublimeText Editor**" then the VBNewLines are recognized...

> UPDATE

Tried using Environment.NewLine but I get the same result.

This is a example text copied from my richtextbox pasted in the Notepad:

```
Escape the Fate - Ungrateful (2013)http://vk.com/doc3197020_179614905?hash=97855f387cf7d8a85bThe King Is Dead - Once Upon A Burning House [EP] (2013)http://vk.com/doc3197020_183005958?hash=bdea3f04fe101eae11Sleeping With Sirens - Alone [single] (2013)http://vk.com/doc3197020_182922598?hash=27e50a03a30b4ec89cPalisades - Outcasts (2013)http://vk.com/doc3197020_182588309?hash=90f629956bcfc59029Done!
```

this is the same text pasted in other editors:

```
Escape the Fate - Ungrateful (2013)
http://vk.com/doc3197020_179614905?hash=97855f387cf7d8a85b

The King Is Dead - Once Upon A Burning House [EP] (2013)
http://vk.com/doc3197020_183005958?hash=bdea3f04fe101eae11

Sleeping With Sirens - Alone [single] (2013)
http://vk.com/doc3197020_182922598?hash=27e50a03a30b4ec89c

Palisades - Outcasts (2013)
http://vk.com/doc3197020_182588309?hash=90f629956bcfc59029

Done!
```

Comment: What do you expect to see on the Notepad?

Comment: Try Environment.NewLine

Comment: @bigcake tried with Environment.NewLine

Comment: @Steve I updated my question with that info

Comment: Just for testing, what happen if you don't replace the vbNewLine (or Environment.NewLine) i.e. `Clipboard.SetText(RichTextBox1.Text)`?

Comment: @Steve yes the first I've tested is without using replace but nothing :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripMenuItem2.Click
    Dim curStart As Integer = RichTextBox1.SelectionStart
    Dim curLength As Integer = RichTextBox1.SelectionLength

    RichTextBox1.SelectAll()
    RichTextBox1.Copy()

    RichTextBox1.Select(curStart, curLength)
    RichTextBox1.Focus()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but do you know if I can do it without selecting the entire text?, the thing is I have selected a line, then I use right-click to open a contextmenu and select a "copy all" option, I want to preserve the current selected line after the "copy all" operation.

Comment: Sure...just save the current selection start and length, then reset it when you're done.  See above.